# Add local music to spotify playlist

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, playlist

I've been looking through the Spotify API https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference and also searched multiple webpages but can't find anything.

Is it possible to add music from your local computer ex(C:downloads\music\song.mp3) into a spotify playlist with js or their API

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it's not possible at this point in time.

Comment: Sad the hear that. When you say the simple answer in no, does that mean that there is a way? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Didn't mean to give a confusion answer - the answer is that there's no way to do that and that there are no short-term plans of adding support for it. It's not that we don't want to add it, it'd be awesome, but it is not prioritised right now.